# Firebase database throwing "Error: Reference.set failed"

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to push a set of data to my firebase database but keep returning  error. Have been trying the different fixes but none of them worked.

This is a picture of the error page: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVo4k.png)

```
Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'opportunities.-LIR7YgffdqEs86nggb6.opportunityTitle'
```

Would be forever grateful if anyone could help me:)

Code:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.addOpportunity = this.addOpportunity.bind(this);
    this.removeOpportunity = this.removeOpportunity.bind(this);

    this.app = firebase.initializeApp(DB_CONFIG);
    this.database = this.app.database().ref().child('opportunities');

    //We are going to setup the React state of our component
    this.state = {
      opportunities: [],
    }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    const previousOpportunities = this.state.opportunities;

    // Data Snapshot
    this.database.on('child_added', snap => {
      previousOpportunities.push({
        id: snap.key,
        opportunityTitle: snap.val(),
        opportunityCompany: snap.val().opportunityCompany,
        opportunityLocation: snap.val().opportunityLocation,
        opportunityDescription: snap.val().opportunityDescription,
        opportunityLink: snap.val().opportunityLink,
      })

      this.setState({
        opportunities: previousOpportunities
      })
    })

    this.database.on('child_removed', snap => {
      for(var i=0; i < previousOpportunities.length; i++){
        if(previousOpportunities[i].id === snap.key){
          previousOpportunities.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }

    this.setState({
      opportunities: previousOpportunities
    })
  })
}

  addOpportunity(){
    this.database.push().set({opportunityTitle: this.state.newopportunityTitle,
                              opportunityCompany: this.state.newopportunityCompany,
                              opportunityLocation: this.state.newopportunityLocation,
                              opportunityDescription: this.state.newopportunityDescription,
                              opportunityLink: this.state.newopportunityLink});
  }
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Should be added now, thanks @Colin

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `this.state.opportunityTitle` instead of `this.state.newopportunityTitle`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Colin! It seemed to be working when I did the following: addOpportunity(newOpportunityTitle, newopportunityCompany, newopportunityLocation, newopportunityDescription, newopportunityLink){
    this.database.push({opportunityTitle: newOpportunityTitle,
                              opportunityCompany: newopportunityCompany,
                              opportunityLocation: newopportunityLocation,
                              opportunityDescription: newopportunityDescription,
                              opportunityLink: newopportunityLink});
  }

Comment: Cool, if the answer helped please upvote and or mark as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Colin! It seemed to be working when I did the following:

```
addOpportunity(newOpportunityTitle, newopportunityCompany, 
newopportunityLocation, newopportunityDescription, newopportunityLink){

this.database.push({opportunityTitle: newOpportunityTitle,
                    opportunityCompany: newopportunityCompany,
                    opportunityLocation: newopportunityLocation,
                    opportunityDescription: newopportunityDescription,
                    opportunityLink: newopportunityLink});
```

}